# PowerBi - can we embed in software and distribute to clients?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

This question probably has a simple answer that I can not find (I'm very new to Power BI). The scenario is that we have software that runs in the browser (ASP.NET MVC) that is hosted on a client's site on their infrastructure. In this scenario is it possible to distribute a Power BI dashboard that runs a DirectQuery on to Microsoft SQL Server?

Apologies if this is a dumb question. I am currently on chapter one of a book on Power BI and I don't want to proceed if it can't meet this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. [Power BI Embedded](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-embedded/) provides you a set of [APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/) to embed Power BI reports/dashboards into your own applications.

Long answer: It depends. If you need a total self-hosted solution including Power BI, you'll need to go for [Power BI Premium](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-pro/), which can be an order of magnitude more [expensive](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/calculator/) than Power BI Embedded, making it an impractical solution to offer on top of your software.

Answer (score 1):

maybe a clarification and a small correction, embedding of Power BI and Power BI Embedded both start at the same price level. Through Office you purchase a Premium capacity for Powerbi.com starting at a monthly commitment of $650 You can also use the $9.90 PRO license per user. PBIE is purchased through Azure with no commitment so you can start at $1 an hour ($750 a month)

Please start by exploring our developer center to find which solution is the best fit for your needs [Power BI Developer Center](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/developers/)
Hope this helps
Aviv

Comment: Thank you for this information. To clarify my understanding: purchasing a Power BI Embedded license enables me to embed reports/dashboards in my application and distribute them as read only to my users. I require a Power BI Pro licence to create reports and dashboards.

Comment: We enable embedding in both RO and RW modes, you can review our embed modes here: https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html. You need a single Power BI  PRO license to authenticate your embedding App to create the content and embed it